# Writing base64 image to filesystem in React project

Tags: node.js

I'm successfully converting and sending an image to base64 in my React frontend.

This is received in 'req.body.imageString'. When I receive it, I'm then removing the unnecessary text at the front of the base64 string, using the .pop() method.

However, when I'm then attempting to write the file to my filesystem to be saved and queried later, it isn't saving anything despite there being no error, and it successfully console logging.

Here's my serverless function I'm using:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {

    let base64Image = req.body.imageString 

    let finalImageString = base64Image.split(';base64,').pop()

    fs.writeFile('assets/profilePictures/', finalImageString, { encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
        console.log("File successfully written.")
    })

    res.send(200)

}
```

What I'd like to do is save the file into my 'assets' folder in my React app. So this would be the basic high level structure:

```
/root
// api
/// myServerlessFunction.js
// public
/// assets
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: `'assets' folder in my React app`. React code is sent to the client. A react app cannot be treated as a server. For your server though, try `multer` node package.

Comment: Thank you - think Multer is what I’m looking for. I’ll test it out soon.